# Building ETL logic in Spark Scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm a newbie in Spark Scala world. I'm trying replicate a ETL logic in the same. So essentially, I want to create dynamic code wherein I need to extract the from tables where a particular column exists, do a filter on this column then store its data to Azure blob.

```
val url = "<Host Address>"
val user = "<Username>"
val pw = "<Password>"
val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
val sslfactory = "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"

var sql_lookup = " select * from information_schema.tables as inf_schema left join (SELECT table_schema as country_table_schema ,table_name as country_table_name, column_name as country_table_column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'Schema_name' AND columns.column_name = 'Column_A') as country on inf_schema.table_schema = country.country_table_schema and inf_schema.table_name = country.country_table_name WHERE inf_schema.table_schema='<Schemaname>'"

var dfTbl = (spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("ssl","true")
      .option("sslfactory",sslfactory)
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", pw)
      .option("driver", driver)
      .option("query",sql_lookup)
      .load())

var dfTbl_withCountry = (dfTbl.select(dfTbl.col("*")).filter(dfTbl.col( "country_table_column_name" ).isNotNull)).select("table_name")


val dfTbl_wc = dfTbl_withCountry.collect().foreach(row => row.toSeq.foreach(col => (col)))

for (table <- dfTbl_wc ){
  
  var sql = " select * from <Schemaname>."+s"${table}" + " where <Colume_name> = '<Value>'"
  
   var df = (spark.read
                  .format("jdbc")
                  .option("url", url)
                  .option("ssl","true")
                  .option("sslfactory",sslfactory)
                  .option("user", user)
                  .option("password", pw)
                  .option("driver", driver)
                  .option("query",sql)
                  .load())
  
   var File_withCountry = df
        .coalesce(1)
        .write
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header","true")
        .option("delimiter", "~")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
        .csv("wasbs://<BlobContainer>@<StorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<Targetdirectory>/"+s"${table}")
  
  
  val partition_path = dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://<BlobContainer>@<StorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<Targetdirectory>/"+s"${table}")
     .filter(file=>file.name.startsWith("part"))(0).path

dbutils.fs.cp(partition_path,"wasbs://<BlobContainer>@<StorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<Targetdirectory>/"+s"${table}"+".csv")

dbutils.fs.rm (partition_path, recurse = true)
  
}
```

Below is the query output inner sub-query

```
SELECT table_schema as country_table_schema ,table_name as country_table_name, column_name as country_table_column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '<Schema_name>' AND columns.column_name = 'Column_A'
```

[image]

Each of the tablenames which are the output of dataframe sql_lookup in column 'country_table_name', I want to extract them.
I'm storing its output in dataframe dfTbl. So, in dataframe dfTbl_wc , I'm iterating each row within dataframe dfTbl. On this I'm using for loop to select complete data from each of row in dataframe in dfTbl_wc

But for some reason this code is not working properly in the for loop section.
Please help!

Comment: What is the error or issue you are facing? For loop is not working properly does not give any context.

Comment: Null pointer exception and error: value dataframe is not a member of Unit

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya - Any clue ??

Comment: provide some test data in the question so that I can help you out

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya - I've edited the post to give more info. Does this makes sense ?

Comment: To an extent. I am adding answer below .. see if it is what you required.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya - Many thanks for the answer. Sorry to bother again but is it possible to create dataframe df (where tablenames are hardcoded ) to pass a sql query which will give me all the table names in one single column? I believe that needs to be pivoted before creating the Rdd

Comment: Can you be more specific? Also does my answer relates to what you wanted?

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya - I want to extract data from all such tables in the source Postgres database that has column_A as one of its attributes and dump this to a particular blob location as csv files

Comment: I might be wrong but you can easily do that by making some modification to the code that i have provided.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya -  ```error: not found: type DataFrame
var QueryArrayDF: Array[DataFrame] = new Array[DataFrame](rowscount)
                        ^
error: not found: type DataFrame
var QueryArrayDF: Array[DataFrame] = new Array[DataFrame](rowscount)
                                               ^ error: overloaded method value option with alternatives:
 cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.Row)
                  .option("query",queryArray(i))
                   ^ ```

Comment: use import statement like this `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` .. I have updated the answer with this import statement.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya - ``` error: overloaded method value option with alternatives:
  (key: String,value: Double)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader <and>
  (key: String,value: Long)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader <and>
  (key: String,value: Boolean)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader <and>
  (key: String,value: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
 cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.Row)
                  .option("query",queryArray(i)) ```

Comment: check now as I have updated how query gets created with additional parenthesis

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya - Nope, Still facing same issue. I might be wrong, but I even tried with below change as well : val rowscount = df1.length and val rowscount = queryArray.length

Comment: change .option("query",queryArray(i).toString())

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya - For some reason now I'm getting new error - 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "["

Comment: change .option("query",queryArray(i).toString().replace("[","").replace("]",""))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked the code a bit (essentially combined the code I used earlier and few lines from the one shared by @NikunjKakadiya) and it worked for me. Sharing the code for reference -

```
val sql="select inf_schema.table_name, inf_schema.table_schema, country_table_column_name from information_schema.tables as inf_schema left join (SELECT table_schema as country_table_schema ,table_name as country_table_name, column_name as country_table_column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '<Schema>' AND columns.column_name = 'Column_A') as country on inf_schema.table_schema = country.country_table_schema and inf_schema.table_name = country.country_table_name WHERE inf_schema.table_schema='<Schema>'"

var dfTbl = (spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("ssl","true")
      .option("sslfactory",sslfactory)
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", pw)
      .option("driver", driver)
      .option("query",sql)
      .load())

val df = dfTbl.select(dfTbl.col("table_name")).where(dfTbl.col("country_table_column_name").isNotNull)

println(df)

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df2 = (df.select("table_name").collect())

val rows = df2.length

for (i <- 0 to rows - 1){
      
      println(df2(i).mkString(","))     
      val sql2 = "select * from <Schema>."+df2(i).mkString(",") + " where Column_A = '<Column_Value>'"

  
  println(sql2)
  
  var df_f = (spark.read
                .format("jdbc")
                .option("url", url)
                .option("ssl","true")
                .option("sslfactory",sslfactory)
                .option("user", user)
                .option("password", pw)
                .option("driver", driver)
                .option("query",sql2)
                .load())
  
   var File_withCountry = df_f
        .coalesce(1)
        .write
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header","true")
        .option("delimiter", "~")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
        .csv("wasbs://<Container>@<StorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<TargetDirectory>/"+ df2(i).mkString(",") )
  
   val partition_path = dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://<Container>@<StorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<TargetDirectory>/"+ df2(i).mkString(",")).filter(file=>file.name.startsWith("part"))(0).path

dbutils.fs.cp(partition_path,"wasbs://<Container>@<StorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<TargetDirectory>/"+ df2(i).mkString(",")+".csv")

dbutils.fs.rm (partition_path, recurse = true)
  
  
}
```

Let me in case of any concerns.

Thanks guys for your support. Really Appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: what was the issue that you had with the code posted by me. Try to mention that so that it might be helpful for others.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya - Not much but one thing I noticed is that you used toString method. While doing so it was picking up the square brackets along with the memory address in each of the rows. So it was slight difficult for me to replace all such strings in a single line. So I went for mkString(",") method. Please note, as I'm a newbie, I could be extremely wrong here if I've missed anything else.

Answer (score 1):

To can create a new column in the dataframe that has queries that you want to run. Then you could select the query column and convert that to array and loop over it to get the final dataframe and then do whatever you want with it like saving it as table, parquet files, csv files etc. You want to save each table data separately then you would have to write the code in the for loop below to accomplish that.

```
//source data
val df = Seq(("Schemaname","Table1","Column_A"),("Schemaname","Table2","Column_A"),("Schemaname","Table3","Column_A"),("Schemaname","Table4","Column_A"),("Schemaname","Table5","Column_A"),("Schemaname","Table6","Column_A"))
.toDF("country_table_schema","country_table_name","country_table_column_name")
//add a column for the query that gets generated for each row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

 val df1 = df.withColumn("fulltableName",concat_ws(".",$"country_table_schema",$"country_table_name"))
.withColumn("Query",concat_ws("",concat(lit("("),lit(" Select * from ")) , $"fulltableName" , lit("where column_name = "), concat($"country_table_column_name", lit(") a"))))
.drop("fulltableName")

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
//convert it to array. I am using collect here but if you have large volume don't use collect otherwise it would crash your driver.
val queryArray = df1.select("Query").rdd.collect()
val rowscount = queryArray.length
//create an array of dataframe to hold the details of each query output.
var QueryArrayDF: Array[DataFrame] = new Array[DataFrame](rowscount)
//loop through the query and create dataframe and add that to the array of dataframe
for(i <- 0 to rowscount - 1){
       val df = (spark.read
                  .format("jdbc")
                  .option("url", url)
                  .option("ssl","true")
                  .option("sslfactory",sslfactory)
                  .option("user", user)
                  .option("password", pw)
                  .option("driver", driver)
                  .option("query",queryArray(i).toString().replace("[","").replace("]",""))
                  .load())
      QueryArrayDF(i) = df
    }
// now let's combine the dataframes, if we have more than one
        var CombinedDF = QueryArrayDF(0)
        for (i <- 1 to QueryArrayDF.length - 1) {
          CombinedDF = CombinedDF.union(QueryArrayDF(i))
        }
```

Now you can save the Combined dataframe as you want.